# Enabling Smartedit from Spartacus storefront vs Hybris Smartedit, what's the difference?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront, smartedit

I have Spartacus storefront, and have followed all the steps from this document https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/2.x/smartEdit-setup-instructions-for-spartacus/

But I also have SAP smartedit which I can access anyways. So now I think there are two instances of Smartedit (I don't know if they're reduntant).
What I want to know is the pros of having enabled Smartedit from Spartacus storefront.